Why does an error occur in the library bitcoin.rpc?
An error occurs.
Exception has occurred: TypeError
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
File "C:\test\GetBlock.py", line 2, in 
from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
p = RawProxy()
info = p.getblockchaininfo()
print(info['blocks'])

How to fix the error?
Python 3.12.5
python-bitcoinlib 0.12.2
Windows 10
Updated Python from version 3.9 to the latest.
Reinstalled the library python-bitcoinlib. This library installs without errors and warnings.
The error has not changed

Have you inspected info, e.g. in a debugger, to see what value it has?
